# Can I make the browser follow a link after a certain amount of time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make a hyperlink turn active and go to that page after a certain amount of time or on pageload. Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: Why not just use a meta refresh tag?

Comment: @Jim Lamb: maybe the url he needs to redirect to is somehow dynamic and based on something the user does while on the page?  (just playing devil's advocate here...)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(followLink, 10000); // 10 seconds

function followLink() {
    window.location = jQuery('#myLink').attr('href');
}

jQuery(function() {
    followLink();
});
```

I'll also just note that there's nothing particular to jQuery about this: you could pretty easily do the same thing with plain vanilla JS.

Comment: Yes, the trick in the 'delay' before navigate can be achieved without jquery. Though you can use jquery to easily attach events during runtime. Which one of your examples did.

Comment: Calling .click() on a link doesn't trigger its default behavior, though. It has to be done with window.location, AFAICS.

Comment: Why are you calling it on a timeout and on document ready?  Makes no sense.

Comment: From the OP: "go to that page after a certain amount of time or on pageload"

Answer (score 2):

I like this way of doing it:

On document ready:

```
$(function(){
       window.location = $('#link').attr('href');
});
```

2 seconds after document ready:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = $('#link').attr('href');
    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery script should do the job:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = link.attr('href');
    },3000);
});
```